# "No language is installed in your default TTS Engine"? What should I do?

Tags: text-to-speech

I have just installed a pdf reader in my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone which comes with android 2.3 Gingerbread. This pdf reader has a text to speech option, but I am not able to use it and getting the error message: "No Language installed in your Default TTS Engine".

What should I do? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the speech synthesis data for the TTS engine.  You can find it on the play store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.langpack.installer).

Edit : The installer seems to have been removed from the Play Store for some reason.  It can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/downloads/detail?name=com.svox.langpack.installer_1.0.1.apk).

Comment: The `href` does not work.

Comment: @Try_me34 - It seems to have been removed from the play store for some reason.  I added a new link to it.